# How to understand what content can be put in or outside of curly braces?

Tags: r

As a beginner of R, I have been struggling with reading complicated code (at least for me, it is complicated). When I read simple code, the structure is very clear. I can tell which are arguments, which are variables and something else just like that. Like:

```
x <- c(1, 2, 3)
```

But when I read some complicated code, I get confused. For example:

```
output <- vector("double", ncol(df))  
for (i in seq_along(df)) {            
  output[[i]] <- median(df[[i]]) 
}
output
```

I don't know why it's "in" before seq_along(df) not others (I use ?seq_along but there is no answer). I don't know why "(i in seq_along(df))" isn't in the curly braces. Is it a condition or? if there is a basic logic in programming language through which I can tell what can be put where? How to read complicated code in R, I mean if there is any logic I can follow?

Comment: That is a "for loop".  If you google for loops you will be able to understand what they do, then you will understand how R sets up for loops.

Comment: I googled. But it's just about syntax, but now the inside logic. I mean, indeed, it will tell me, I should put "i in seq_along(df)" before {, but I wanna know why. If there is any generic and basic logic that I can follow. I mean, I don't just wanna know how to put content in this code, I also wanna know how to put content in any code. If there is any rule that what kind of content should be put where.

Comment: Beyond "google is your friend," you can download Roger Peng's [R Programming](https://leanpub.com/rprogramming) for free on leanpub.com, and it includes video tutorials. Chapter 14 covers control flow in R, including the `for()` function, including an example with `seq_along()`.

Comment: if() just an example. I wanna know if there is any rule (very basic stuff) in R that can let me know which kind of content should be put where. For example,, R is sensitive to the lowercase and uppercase. It's a rule. So I know every single time I meet with a "r" and "R", I know they are different. So if I know a rule in R that can let me know which kind of content should be put where, I won't google or use helper any more to explore which content should be put where when using a new function cuz I have a rule , the most basic stuff, to let me know which type of content should be put where.

Comment: You should put things that belong in a for loop that will be processed by iterating using an index.   Just like () {} are used for a lot of purposes including control structures like for loops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic structure of a `for()` function in R is:

```
for(condition that iterates) {
   # do something
}
```

The curly braces operator `{` and `}` takes whatever happened in the previous function `for()` and applies it to the programming statements within the curly braces.

The `[[` within your question is one of the four forms of the [extract operator](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Extract.html). `[[` specifically allows one to extract one element from a list while supporting a computed index. I provide illustrations of three of the forms of the extract operator in my article, [Forms of the Extract Operator](https://github.com/lgreski/datasciencectacontent/blob/master/markdown/rprog-extractOperator.md). The fourth form, `@` (also known as the slot operator) is unique to objects built with the S4 object system in R, and isn't typically used by beginning R programmers.

As far as learning how to read R code, the reference I posted in comments, [R Programming](https://leanpub.com/rprogramming) by Roger Peng, is a reasonable "free" resource since you can decide to pay $0 for it.

## Explanation of code in original post

Here we'll walk through the original example and explain what's happening. Since `df` was undefined in the original post, we'll use the `mtcars` data frame.

```
df <- mtcars

# instantiate a vector object with length equal to number of columns in 
# df, which in this example should be 11
output <- vector("double",ncol(df)) 
length(output)

> length(output)
[1] 11
>
```

At this point we have defined an output vector with length 11, which matches the number of columns in `df`.

Next, the `for()` function sets the value of `i` to unique sequential numbers from 1 to the number of columns in `df`.

We can see this by printing the result of `seq_along()`.

```
# illustrate what seq_along() does
seq_along(df)
> seq_along(df)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11
>
```

For each value of `i`, it calculates the median of the associated column in `df` and saves it to the corresponding element within `output`.

```
# iterate across columns in df, from 1:11 
for (i in seq_along(df)){
     output[[i]] <- median(df[[i]])
}
```

R supports the assignment of names to elements in a vector. To make it obvious what happened in the `for()` loop, we'll set the names of elements in `output` to the column names in `df`, and print the vector.

```
# add names to output vector and print 
names(output) <- colnames(df)
output



> output
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
 19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000   2.000 
>
```

### Importance of the `[[` extract operator

At this point a beginning R user might ask, "Why does this code use the `[[` form of the extract operator instead of `[`?"

The key is that for the code in the original question, the `[` form returns an object of type `data.frame()`, whereas `[[` evaluates the data frame and returns a numeric vector. We can illustrate this with the `str()` function, which returns the structure of an R object.

```
str(df[1]) # returns a data frame
str(df[[1]]) # returns a numeric vector

> str(df[1]) # returns a data frame
'data.frame':   32 obs. of  1 variable:
 $ mpg: num  21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
> str(df[[1]]) # returns a numeric vector
 num [1:32] 21 21 22.8 21.4 18.7 18.1 14.3 24.4 22.8 19.2 ...
>
```

The `median()` function expects a numeric vector as input. Passing it a data frame instead of a vector generates "need numeric data" error.

```
> median(df[1])
Error in median.default(df[1]) : need numeric data
>
```

Another way to explain what R is doing in this situation is that `df[1]` subsets a data frame to return a data frame with a single column, whereas `df[[1]]` not only subsets the data frame to a single column, but also recursively subsets it to return the values in the first column as a vector. By subsetting more than 2 columns, we can cause the recursive subset to fail.

```
# illustrate recursive subsetting with a case that will fail
head(df[1:3]) # print 6 rows of first 3 columns
head(df[[1:3]]) # fails with recursive subset error

> head(df[1:3]) # print 6 rows of first 3 columns
                   mpg cyl disp
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360
Valiant           18.1   6  225
> head(df[[1:3]]) # fails with recursive subset error
Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
>
```

### Many ways to solve a problem in R

Having explained the code in the original question, it's important to note that there are many ways to do something in R. Here we will use a version of `for()` that iterates based on the column names in `df`, and uses the `[[` form of the extract operator to extract the correct column in `df` to calculate its median.

```
# now illustrate same code by iterating over column names
output2 <- vector("double",ncol(df)) 
names(output2) <- colnames(df)
columnNames <- colnames(df)
for (i in columnNames){
     output2[[i]] <- median(df[[i]])
}
output2
> output2
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
 19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000   2.000 
>
```

An important subtlety in this solution is that by assigning names to the elements in `output2` we can use the names to index the output vector as well as the input data frame. In fact, if we hadn't assigned the names the loop would produce inaccurate results, appending the named values at elements 12:22 in the vector.

Finally, as you progress in learning R, you'll learn about the `apply()` family of functions, which allow one to avoid `for()` loops. A solution to the same problem using `lapply()` or "list apply" is illustrated the following code block. The code block also implements an [anonymous function](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functional-programming.html#anonymous-functions), which is like any other R function except it isn't given a name. Since `lapply()` returns a list and we know that each item in the list is a single number, we use `unlist()` to convert the list returned by `lapply()` into a vector.

```
# produce same output with a different technique: lapply()
columnNames <- colnames(df)
output3 <- unlist(lapply(columnNames,function(x){
     median(df[[x]])
}))
names(output3) <- colnames(df)
output3
> output3
    mpg     cyl    disp      hp    drat      wt    qsec      vs      am    gear    carb 
 19.200   6.000 196.300 123.000   3.695   3.325  17.710   0.000   0.000   4.000   2.000 
>
```

Comment: Oh the most useful answer for me so far! Actually I have been struggling with some very basic stuff that can make me "learn by analogy". Thank you so much!

Comment: @Chris - check my updated answer which compares three different techniques to calculate the medians of the columns in a data frame.